# Adding a wait in a switch / case?

Tags: java, android

When a user clicks, case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is triggered. When the click is released, case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is triggered.

I'm interested in determining if ACTION_UP hasn't been triggered within 3 seconds of ACTION_DOWN. Meaning, If 3 seconds have passed since the user has clicked and has not yet released, I want to know, essentially trying to determine a long click.

Is there a way to do such a thing?

```
   switch (event.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
       break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       break;
    }
```

Comment: OnLongClickListener will not work for what I'm trying to do. I'm seeking alternatives.

Comment: Handler is used for hault the time in events(in Android). Once i was stuck with the wait and sleep condition, so it helped me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the right way to detect a long-click is by implementing 
[View.OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html).  This is easier and less error-prone that detecting it yourself, and it ensures that your app fits in well with the rest of the system.

For a custom `View`, you would add `implements View.OnLongClickListener` to your class declaration, add `setOnLongClickListener(this);` to the constructor, and add the `onLongClick()` method to your class:

```
public boolean onLongClick (View v) {
    // Handle long-click
}
```

If your `View` isn't custom you can add the listener like this:

```
theView.setLongClickable(true);
theView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Handle long-click
    }
});
```

**Update:** Okay, I've done some digging, and while this is the right way to do it for every View I've ever worked with, it in fact does not work for SeekBars, which is what the questioner is working with.  This fact is not documented in the `SeekBar` documentation, but experimentation has shown it to be true, and digging through the source code shows why: `SeekBar.onTouchEvent()` does not call `super.onTouchEvent()`. It is in `View.onTouchEvent()` that `performLongClick()` is called, if appropriate.

The way I would implement it if I had to is with `Handler.postDelayed()`.  On ACTION_DOWN, I would post (with e.g. 3000ms delay) a `Runnable` that handles the long-press to a `Handler`, and I'd cancel it on ACTION_UP.  So any press for less than the delay doesn't end up calling the `Runnable`, but if ACTION_UP hasn't occurred after the delay, it is.

That said, I'd caution you to rethink doing this at all.  What does it mean to long-press a `SeekBar`?  If the user is dragging the "thumb" for longer than the delay, suddenly you have a long-press that probably was not meant as one.  You can cancel and reset the delay every time the thumb is moved, requiring a long-press to be several seconds in exactly one position.  But it's rare to be perfectly still; it's in fact difficult to hold the thumb yet not move it for several seconds.  So you could then have a minimum change in thumb position that resets the delay.  That's what I would do if I had to, but I must say it's a very strange user experience.

Comment: You should also add a snippet if possible.

Comment: @Roger `SeekBar` is an (indirect) subclass of `View`, so it should definitely work.  Please post code for how you're adding the listener.

Comment: seekBar1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { @Override public boolean onLongClick(View v) { System.out.println("Long Click"); return true;
   }
         
        });

Comment: @Roger You probably need to call seekBar1.setLongClickable(true); first. Sorry I missed that part.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple and straight forward. You need to get timestamps to evaluate the time differences between events You may do it by something as below example:

```
private static int TIME_MARGIN = 3;  //seconds
private Date d1 = null;

public void OnWhatEverOnClickEvent(Event event){
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           d1 = new Date();
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           Date d2 = new Date();
           if((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) >= (TIME_MARGIN * 1000L)){
               //its a long click due to 3 seconds hold, do something here
           }
        break;
    }
}
```

However, as @Darshan Computing said, you should better make use of `View.OnLongClickListener` which is a hassle free approach.

Comment: Seems like that would only trigger after the click is released. I need to know the point when the click has been held for 3 seconds not whether or not it was held for 3 seconds after it was released.

Comment: when you press a button, DOWN event will raise and from then the **d1** is set. But when you release the button, UP event is raised and within that you are checking if the time difference between to Date objects *(d2-d1)* is more than 3 seconds. I guess it simply offers what you want.

Comment: Regarding *when* the click has been held for three seconds. Simply define a Date object outside the event method and set its value once you fall under if condition of *'do something'*. By this you'll know when the long click event was calculated

Answer (score 0):

When the user has clicked, start a new thread that polls the current state of the button (or introduce a new flag which is set in `DOWN` and reset in `UP`. The thread could poll this state or flag every 100ms and use an internal timestamp to determine if 3 seconds have passed. If so it could fire a new event to start action for a long click